# c memory allocation with malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I have these vars:

```
uint32_t fsize;
char *filebuffer = NULL;
fsize = fileStat.st_size;
```

if i want *to malloc* the right memory the code that i have to write is this:

```
malloc(fsize);
```

or this:

```
malloc(fsize * sizeof(char *));
```

thanks!

Comment: Aaand, what is the "the needed memory"?

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof(char*)` is the size of a pointer, which is probably not what you want. Going by the names, I'm assuming that `fsize` is the size of a file (in bytes), so plain old

```
malloc(fsize);
```

is fine.

`malloc()` allocates the specified number of bytes. If you were to call `malloc(fsize * sizeof(char *))` you'd be allocating too much memory, as you're multiplying the required number of bytes (`fsize`) by an extra factor, `sizeof(char*)`, which is the number of bytes needed to store a pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes).

The fact that you ultimately assign the allocated memory to a `char*` pointer is irrelevant when deciding how many bytes to allocate.

Comment: Edited to hopefully explain better.

Comment: ooooooook! now i've understand!

Comment: The best is to always write like this : `foo = malloc(number * sizeof(*foo));` this way, whatevs the type of foo, this will always be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> if i want to malloc the right memory the code that i have to write is
>   this:
>
> malloc(fsize); or this:
>
> malloc(fsize * sizeof(char *));

The difference between these two statements is malloc(fsize) gives you memory enough to store the characters in the file, malloc(fsize * sizeof(char *)) give you the memory enough to store the address of enough pointers to point to every character in the file.

I think what you ment to ask was:

"or this:  malloc(fsize * sizeof(char));"

in other words do I want to malloc the number of characters in the file times the size of each character, which is a reasonable question, but for characters it's irrelevant because the sizeof(char) = 1. So lets says your file is text and has 4 letters in it:

```
malloc(fsize) == malloc(4)
malloc(fsize * sizeof(char)) == malloc(4 * 1) == malloc(4)
malloc(fsize * sizeof(char *)) == malloc(4 * 4) == malloc(16)
```

The reason it's 4 is because you're not getting the size of the data, but the size of the address (ex: 0x0035F900) in bytes.

Hope that helps clarify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

malloc(size) function allocates a block of size bytes of memory, returning a pointer to the beginning of the block. Like this:

```
uint32_t fsize = fileStat.st_size;
char* filebuffer = (char*)malloc(fsize);
```

and don't forget about

```
free(filebuffer);
```

Comment: I assume that fileStat.st_size contains file size in bytes.

Comment: yes yes! Also could lead to any sort of problem not have written `char *` in the malloc??

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc. Just `#include <stdlib.h>` and you're fine.

Comment: No, it just won't compile because malloc returns pointer to void, but you need pointer to char, so you have to cast it into char*.

Comment: [Do not cast the return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Tutankhamen: This is a C question, look at the tags. Jens is right.

Comment: @Tutankhamen This question is tagged C and in C++ you would use `new` instead of malloc anyway. So there's **never** a reason to cast a malloc return value :-)